# unable to connect mysql db with this code

Tags: php, mysql

```
$hostname='example.com';
$username='someUser';
$password='password';
$dbname='aDataBase';
$usertable='my_table';

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

I'm using a read-only username here. When i test the script, i get the error "unable to select database".

Any clue?

Comment: Have you considered actually looking at the error, rather than suppressing it and using a `die()`?

Comment: yeah, just did that now. This is what i get: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Comment: Remove the error suppressing @. It's suppressing the errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use fixed strings for your die() message...They're useless for diagnosis. As well, don't supress errors with `@`.

```
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
```

Using this you'll get the exact reason things are failing.

Comment: hey thanks for that! Just tried it and this is what i get: "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111" any idea on what that is?

Comment: using a generic `die()` is good after you have a finished product, but when you working on it `mysql_error()` is your best friend.

Comment: Possibly a firewall issue, since it appears you're connecting to a remote DB server.

Comment: are you getting the error on the connect or the DB select? to find out add `'connection error '.` and `'selection error '.` to the beginning of the respective `die()`'s

Comment: where would the firewall issue be? My computer, my website server? or the actual sql db?

Comment: @vaughn so something like this:mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or 'connection error' 'selection error' die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or 'connection error' 'selection error' die(mysql_error()); ? If thats wrong, could you give me an example code please. Thank you!

Comment: mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die('connection error '.mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($dbname) or   die('selection error '.mysql_error()); here you go, it show what one is failing, BTW are you using godaddy os your host?

Comment: Hey thanks! Yes i am using godaddy. I know they're a right pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$db_name = "DATABASE";
$db_user = "USER";
$db_pass = "1234";
$db_serv = "localhost";

$res = @mysql_connect($db_serv,$db_user ,$db_pass);

if($res)
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
```